# Problems when using x265 with video-react from phone

Tags: reactjs, xiaomi, video-reactjs

I am developing an app using ReactJS and in this app I have installed the library video-react.
I am trying to play a video using that has the following encoding (x265 HEVC 10BIT AAC 5.1 silence). Whenever I play the video through my pc it works fine, however when I try to play the video through localhost on my phone (which is a Xiaomi 12) I only get the ambient audio and no speech. Anyone ever encountered this issue?

Thanks